# Passing variable from a class to another class - not working

Tags: java, swing, variables, actionlistener

I am doing a project and I got stuck. I want to pass a variable from one class to the another one. The two classes are posted beneath.

I am talking about the variable "private int index", I want from my ActionListener to another ActionListener. This can be achieved by making it static but that implies I have to make it "public" and I tried to do it with getters and setters but it is not working as it should.

Can you help me?

---

ShowMembersGUI.java

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import domains.Member;
import mappers.MemberMapper;

public class ShowMembersGUI {
        private JFrame showMembersFrame;
        private JButton editMemberBtn, closeBtn, removeMemberBtn;
        private JTable table;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private JPanel p;
        private Object id, fName, lName;
        private int index;

        public ShowMembersGUI() {
                MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
                List<Member> data = mMapper.selectAllMembers();
                final MyTableModel m = new MyTableModel(data);

                table = new JTable(m);
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

                DefaultTableCellRenderer leftRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                leftRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(leftRenderer);

                editMemberBtn = new JButton("Rediger Medlem");
                editMemberBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                                // int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                                id = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                                index = (Integer) id;
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, index);
                                EditMemberGUI editMemberGUI = new EditMemberGUI();
                                editMemberGUI.showGUI();
                        }
                });

                removeMemberBtn = new JButton("Fjern Medlem");
                removeMemberBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                                // int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                                id = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                                fName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                                lName = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 2);

                                Object[] options = { "Ja", "Nej" };
                                int n = JOptionPane
                                                .showOptionDialog(null,
                                                                "Er du sikker du vil slette medlem?\n\n"
                                                                                + "Medlemsnr: " + id + "\n\n" + fName
                                                                                + " " + lName, "Advarsel",
                                                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                                                                options[0]);

                                if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                        MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
                                        int i = (Integer) id;
                                        mMapper.removeMember(i);
                                        m.removeMemberFromTable(row);
                                        m.fireTableDataChanged();
                                } else {
                                }

                        }
                });

                closeBtn = new JButton("Close");
                closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                showMembersFrame.setVisible(false);
                        }
                });

                p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                p.add(editMemberBtn);
                p.add(removeMemberBtn);
                p.add(closeBtn);

        }

        public JTable getTable() {
                return table;
        }

        public void setTable(JTable table) {
                this.table = table;
        }

        public void showGUI() {
                showMembersFrame = new JFrame();
                showMembersFrame.setTitle("Vis Medlemmer");
                showMembersFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                showMembersFrame.setSize(900, 600);

                showMembersFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                showMembersFrame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                // showMembersFrame.pack();
                showMembersFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public int getIndex() {
                return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
                this.index = index;
        }

}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        /**
                 *
                 */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();

        public MyTableModel(List<Member> members) {
                this.members = members;
        }

        public void addMember(Member m) {
                members.add(m);
                int row = members.size() - 1;
                fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

        public void removeMemberFromTable(int row) {
                members.remove(row);
                fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }

        public List<Member> getTeachers() {
                return new ArrayList<Member>(members);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
                return 8;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
                return members.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                Member m = members.get(rowIndex);

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                        return m.getMemberId();

                case 1:
                        return m.getfName();

                case 2:
                        return m.getlName();

                case 3:
                        return m.getAddress();

                case 4:
                        return m.getZipCode();

                case 5:
                        return m.getCity();

                case 6:
                        return m.getEmail();

                case 7:
                        return m.getPhoneNo();

                default:
                        return "";
                }
        }

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                        return "MedlemsID";

                case 1:
                        return "Fornavn";

                case 2:
                        return "Efternavn";

                case 3:
                        return "Adresse";

                case 4:
                        return "Postnummer";

                case 5:
                        return "By";

                case 6:
                        return "Email";

                case 7:
                        return "Telefonnr";
                default:
                        return "";
                }
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                        return Integer.class;

                case 2:
                        return String.class;

                case 3:
                        return String.class;

                default:
                        return String.class;
                }
        }
}
```

---

EditMemberGUI.java

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import mappers.MemberMapper;
import domains.Member;

public class EditMemberGUI {
        private JFrame editMemberFrame;
        private JPanel btnsPanel, panel;
        private JButton editBtn, cancelBtn;
        private JLabel fNameLbl, lNameLbl, addressLbl, zipCodeLbl, cityLbl, emailLbl,
                                        phoneNoLbl;
        private JTextField fNameTF, lNameTF, addressTF, zipCodeTF, cityTF, emailTF,
        phoneNoTF; ;
        private GridLayout layout;

        public EditMemberGUI(){

                layout = new GridLayout(0,2,1,0);

                panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(layout);
                layout.setVgap(0);

                fNameLbl = new JLabel("Fornavn: ");
                fNameTF = new JTextField(15);

                lNameLbl = new JLabel("Efternavn: ");
                lNameTF = new JTextField(15);

                addressLbl = new JLabel("Adresse: ");
                addressTF = new JTextField(15);


                zipCodeLbl = new JLabel("Postnummer: ");
                zipCodeTF = new JTextField(15);

                cityLbl = new JLabel("By: ");
                cityTF = new JTextField(15);

                emailLbl = new JLabel("Email: ");
                emailTF = new JTextField(15);

                phoneNoLbl = new JLabel("Telefonnr: ");
                phoneNoTF = new JTextField(15);

                panel.add(fNameLbl);
                panel.add(fNameTF);
                panel.add(lNameLbl);
                panel.add(lNameTF);
                panel.add(addressLbl);
                panel.add(addressTF);
                panel.add(zipCodeLbl);
                panel.add(zipCodeTF);
                panel.add(cityLbl);
                panel.add(cityTF);
                panel.add(emailLbl);
                panel.add(emailTF);
                panel.add(phoneNoLbl);
                panel.add(phoneNoTF);


                //------------

                btnsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

                editBtn = new JButton("Redigér");
                editBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                ShowMembersGUI s = new ShowMembersGUI();

                                int zipCode = Integer.parseInt(zipCodeTF.getText());
                                Member m = new Member(fNameTF.getText(), lNameTF.getText(),
                                                addressTF.getText(), zipCode, cityTF.getText(),
                                                emailTF.getText(), phoneNoTF.getText());
                                MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
                                int i = s.getIndex();
                                mMapper.editMember(m, i);

                                int dialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vil du gerne se oversigten over medlemmer?",
                                                "WARNING", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                if(dialog == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                        ShowMembersGUI showMembersGUI = new ShowMembersGUI();
                                        showMembersGUI.showGUI();
                                        editMemberFrame.setVisible(false);
                                } else {
                                        editMemberFrame.setVisible(false);
                                }
                        }      
                });
                cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                editMemberFrame.setVisible(false);
                        }      
                });

                btnsPanel.add(editBtn);
                btnsPanel.add(cancelBtn);

        }

        public void showGUI() {

                editMemberFrame = new JFrame();
                editMemberFrame.setTitle("Redigér Medlem");
                editMemberFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                editMemberFrame.setSize(400,300);

                editMemberFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                editMemberFrame.add(btnsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                editMemberFrame.pack();
                editMemberFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your index getter or setter, but your `case` statements in `ShowMembersGUI` won't work as you expect - you'll need a `break;` after each one

Comment: My case statements work fine.

Comment: @NickJ he is using return.  Breaks aren't needed and perhaps some compilers will issue "unreachable code" warnings.

Comment: Yes, good point. Should have looked closer.

Comment: where you need to access your `index` ? in which `ActionListener`?

Comment: In the first ActionListener of my EditMemberGUI.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to your instance for example:

1) pass reference of `ShowMembersGUI` to your `EditMemberGUI` :

```
     editMemberBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                        // int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
                        id = (Object) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                        index = (Integer) id;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, index);
                        EditMemberGUI editMemberGUI = new EditMemberGUI(ShowMembersGUI.this);
                        editMemberGUI.showGUI();
                }
        });
```

or pass only `index` if only it needed change `EditMemberGUI editMemberGUI = new EditMemberGUI(ShowMembersGUI.this);` to `EditMemberGUI editMemberGUI = new EditMemberGUI(index);`

2) Change costructor of `EditMemberGUI` to `public EditMemberGUI(Integer index)` or `public EditMemberGUI(ShowMembersGUI gui)`

3) assing a parametr to a instance variable of `EditMemberGUI` (showMembersGUI/index).

4) and then use it in your actionListener like `int i = EditMemberGUI.this.showMembersGUI.getIndex();` or `int i = index;`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will definitely look into your answers.